# Using awk/sed to change columns

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

This is the text file I have:

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
*****
 22 22 0 0 0
SMALL
GASTEIGER

@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C4         24.2940  -24.1240   -0.0710 C.3   167  JZ4167     -0.0650
      2 C7         21.5530  -27.2140   -4.1120 C.ar  167  JZ4167     -0.0613
      3 C8         22.0680  -26.7470   -5.3310 C.ar  167  JZ4167     -0.0583
      4 C9         22.6710  -25.5120   -5.4480 C.ar  167  JZ4167     -0.0199
      5 C10        22.7690  -24.7300   -4.2950 C.ar  167  JZ4167      0.1200
      6 C11        21.6930  -26.4590   -2.9540 C.ar  167  JZ4167     -0.0551
      7 C12        22.2940  -25.1870   -3.0750 C.ar  167  JZ4167     -0.0060
      8 C13        22.4630  -24.4140   -1.8080 C.3   167  JZ4167     -0.0245
      9 C14        23.9250  -24.7040   -1.3940 C.3   167  JZ4167     -0.0518
     10 OAB        23.4120  -23.5360   -4.3420 O.3   167  JZ4167     -0.5065
     11 H          25.3133  -24.3619    0.1509 H       1  UNL1        0.0230
     12 H          23.6591  -24.5327    0.6872 H       1  UNL1        0.0230
     13 H          24.1744  -23.0611   -0.1016 H       1  UNL1        0.0230
     14 H          21.0673  -28.1238   -4.0754 H       1  UNL1        0.0618
     15 H          21.9931  -27.3472   -6.1672 H       1  UNL1        0.0619
     16 H          23.0361  -25.1783   -6.3537 H       1  UNL1        0.0654
     17 H          21.3701  -26.8143   -2.0405 H       1  UNL1        0.0621
     18 H          21.7794  -24.7551   -1.0588 H       1  UNL1        0.0314
     19 H          22.2659  -23.3694   -1.9301 H       1  UNL1        0.0314
     20 H          24.5755  -24.2929   -2.1375 H       1  UNL1        0.0266
     21 H          24.0241  -25.7662   -1.3110 H       1  UNL1        0.0266
     22 H          23.7394  -23.2120   -5.1580 H       1  UNL1        0.2921
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1     4     3   ar
     2     4     5   ar
     3     3     2   ar
     4    10     5    1
     5     5     7   ar
     6     2     6   ar
     7     7     6   ar
     8     7     8    1
     9     8     9    1
    10     9     1    1
    11     1    11    1
    12     1    12    1
    13     1    13    1
    14     2    14    1
    15     3    15    1
    16     4    16    1
    17     6    17    1
    18     8    18    1
    19     8    19    1
    20     9    20    1
    21     9    21    1
    22    10    22    1
```

What I want to do is replace the second last column ie the column with JZ4167 and UNL1, and have it be entirely JZ4, and the third last column to be all 1s.

So my expected output is:

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
*****
 22 22 0 0 0
SMALL
GASTEIGER

@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C4         24.2940  -24.1240   -0.0710 C.3     1  JZ4        -0.0650
      2 C7         21.5530  -27.2140   -4.1120 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0613
      3 C8         22.0680  -26.7470   -5.3310 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0583
      4 C9         22.6710  -25.5120   -5.4480 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0199
      5 C10        22.7690  -24.7300   -4.2950 C.ar    1  JZ4         0.1200
      6 C11        21.6930  -26.4590   -2.9540 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0551
      7 C12        22.2940  -25.1870   -3.0750 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0060
      8 C13        22.4630  -24.4140   -1.8080 C.3     1  JZ4        -0.0245
      9 C14        23.9250  -24.7040   -1.3940 C.3     1  JZ4        -0.0518
     10 OAB        23.4120  -23.5360   -4.3420 O.3     1  JZ4        -0.5065
     11 H          25.3133  -24.3619    0.1509 H       1  JZ4         0.0230
     12 H          23.6591  -24.5327    0.6872 H       1  JZ4         0.0230
     13 H          24.1744  -23.0611   -0.1016 H       1  JZ4         0.0230
     14 H          21.0673  -28.1238   -4.0754 H       1  JZ4         0.0618
     15 H          21.9931  -27.3472   -6.1672 H       1  JZ4         0.0619
     16 H          23.0361  -25.1783   -6.3537 H       1  JZ4         0.0654
     17 H          21.3701  -26.8143   -2.0405 H       1  JZ4         0.0621
     18 H          21.7794  -24.7551   -1.0588 H       1  JZ4         0.0314
     19 H          22.2659  -23.3694   -1.9301 H       1  JZ4         0.0314
     20 H          24.5755  -24.2929   -2.1375 H       1  JZ4         0.0266
     21 H          24.0241  -25.7662   -1.3110 H       1  JZ4         0.0266
     22 H          23.7394  -23.2120   -5.1580 H       1  JZ4         0.2921
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1     4     3   ar
     2     4     5   ar
     3     3     2   ar
     4    10     5    1
     5     5     7   ar
     6     2     6   ar
     7     7     6   ar
     8     7     8    1
     9     8     9    1
    10     9     1    1
    11     1    11    1
    12     1    12    1
    13     1    13    1
    14     2    14    1
    15     3    15    1
    16     4    16    1
    17     6    17    1
    18     8    18    1
    19     8    19    1
    20     9    20    1
    21     9    21    1
    22    10    22    1
```

I have been using sed to replace JZ4167 to JZ4 and UNL1 to JZ4, using
`sed 's/JZ4167/JZ4/g' myfile` and `sed 's/UNL1/JZ4/g' myfile`,
but I can't do `sed 's/167/1/g' myfile` safely, since I might have a `167` in my coordinates, and I don't want to mess up my coordinates. I was wondering if there was a way to do this with awk or something of that sort.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you care about retaining the layout or can all white space be compressed to single blank chars, for example?

Comment: Yes, I would like to retain the way these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to preserve column widths, this may be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^@/ {
    inBlock=( $1 == "@<TRIPOS>ATOM" ? 1 : 0 )
    print
    next
}
inBlock {
    $0 = substr($0,1,53) sprintf("%3s  %-10s %7s",1,"JZ4",$NF)
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
*****
 22 22 0 0 0
SMALL
GASTEIGER

@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C4         24.2940  -24.1240   -0.0710 C.3     1  JZ4        -0.0650
      2 C7         21.5530  -27.2140   -4.1120 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0613
      3 C8         22.0680  -26.7470   -5.3310 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0583
      4 C9         22.6710  -25.5120   -5.4480 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0199
      5 C10        22.7690  -24.7300   -4.2950 C.ar    1  JZ4         0.1200
      6 C11        21.6930  -26.4590   -2.9540 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0551
      7 C12        22.2940  -25.1870   -3.0750 C.ar    1  JZ4        -0.0060
      8 C13        22.4630  -24.4140   -1.8080 C.3     1  JZ4        -0.0245
      9 C14        23.9250  -24.7040   -1.3940 C.3     1  JZ4        -0.0518
     10 OAB        23.4120  -23.5360   -4.3420 O.3     1  JZ4        -0.5065
     11 H          25.3133  -24.3619    0.1509 H       1  JZ4         0.0230
     12 H          23.6591  -24.5327    0.6872 H       1  JZ4         0.0230
     13 H          24.1744  -23.0611   -0.1016 H       1  JZ4         0.0230
     14 H          21.0673  -28.1238   -4.0754 H       1  JZ4         0.0618
     15 H          21.9931  -27.3472   -6.1672 H       1  JZ4         0.0619
     16 H          23.0361  -25.1783   -6.3537 H       1  JZ4         0.0654
     17 H          21.3701  -26.8143   -2.0405 H       1  JZ4         0.0621
     18 H          21.7794  -24.7551   -1.0588 H       1  JZ4         0.0314
     19 H          22.2659  -23.3694   -1.9301 H       1  JZ4         0.0314
     20 H          24.5755  -24.2929   -2.1375 H       1  JZ4         0.0266
     21 H          24.0241  -25.7662   -1.3110 H       1  JZ4         0.0266
     22 H          23.7394  -23.2120   -5.1580 H       1  JZ4         0.2921
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1     4     3   ar
     2     4     5   ar
     3     3     2   ar
     4    10     5    1
     5     5     7   ar
     6     2     6   ar
     7     7     6   ar
     8     7     8    1
     9     8     9    1
    10     9     1    1
    11     1    11    1
    12     1    12    1
    13     1    13    1
    14     2    14    1
    15     3    15    1
    16     4    16    1
    17     6    17    1
    18     8    18    1
    19     8    19    1
    20     9    20    1
    21     9    21    1
    22    10    22    1
```

Comment: i am trying to understand how you have set up your code, as I am still trying to learn awk. Do you have any recommendations on learning awk?

Comment: `inBlock=($1 == "@<TRIPOS>ATOM")` should be enough

Comment: @karakfa it is, I just usually spell it out for clarity (unless I'm golf-ing or just being lazy!) since it's just an extra couple of characters and IMHO it makes a significant improvement to the clarity, especially for people new to the language.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` one-liner:

```
sed '/^@<TRIPOS>ATOM$/,/^@/{/^@/!s/.\{16\}\(.\{7\}\)$/  1  JZ4        \1/;}' file
```

It operates on an address range, from the line consisting of `@<TRIPOS>ATOM` to the line beginning with the `@`. Since lines of interest are fixed-width, it modifies the last 23 characters, keeping the last 7 characters, regardless of the contents of the line.